# XCode iOS project failing to build on other computer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

So I'm trying to share my project (iOS/Swift) with team members and I hosted it on Bitbucket.  They have no issue downloading the latest repo and launching it, but the build is getting errors because of dependency issues with a few external frameworks. Originally this was occurring because I didn't actually upload those frameworks to Bitbucket, but since then I've moved them into the project director and re-linked them to the project, but still getting errors:

[image]

I've included those frameworks into the project just as described in their READMEs (e.g. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and everything works great on my computer, so I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it is Code Sign issues rather than external framework issues.

Please be sure your team sharing same p12 file and provision

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  p12?  provision?

Comment: it's certificates that to be used to build project

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this issue? I don't know anything abotu code signs.

Comment: it's a bit need explanation and here is too short to explain. Just have a look https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html